# Statistical test for comparing usability of two different systems

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, survival, count-data

I conducted a usability test of two password systems ps1 and ps2. Same users participated in the usability of both system. Analysis of average login attempts and average login time clearly indicates that ps1 is more usable than ps2. However, I would like to know which statistical tests are more relevant for comparing the usability of ps1 vs ps2. Or are mean login attempts and login time sufficient indicators?

Also I read about t-test which is used to compare two different samples. However in my study I have used the same sample (users) to determine the usability of ps1 and ps2.

Comment: You might find useful reading about a/b testing. [This](http://research.uncc.edu/sites/research.uncc.edu/files/media/files/Designing%20Experiments2.pptx) might be an interesting piece to get the basics of design of experiments.

Comment: Thanks, but a/b testing assumes testing two variants on different samples (users). I have tested two variants on the same samples (users).

Comment: Can I use a Mann-Whitney U test?

Comment: Mann-Whitney U test still comes with strong assumptions about independence. Can those hold? How did you execute your experiment?

Answer (score 1):

Whether just reporting the means (presumably with confidence intervals) is sufficient is a judgment about your intended audience.  We couldn't answer that for you.

If you want to submit these analyses to a peer-reviewed scientific journal that required a test and a p-value, you should not use t-tests.  Neither of your measures could really be normally distributed.  Your number of login attempts is a kind of count variable (specifically a [negative binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution) with $r=1$, cf, [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/229614/7290)), and the login time is a [survival](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_analysis) time.  There are appropriate models for both.  Also bear in mind that you need to account for the nonindependence in your data.  Probably the simplest option for you would be to use the [Wilcoxon signed rank test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test).  My guess is that these contain the same information, and you could get away with just testing one of them.